# Compare Dataframes using multivariable conditions

Tags: pandas, merge

I am having troubles using merge to find out the value of a column. I have two data frames:

df Conditions

```
A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  | F |
A1 | B1  |     |     |     | F1|
A2 | B2  |     |     |     | F2|
A3 | B3  |     |  D3 |     | F3|
A4 | B4  |     |  D4 |  E4 | F4|
```

df Result

```
A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  | G  | H  | 
A1 | B1  |  C1 |  D1 |  E1 | G1 | H1 |
A2 | B2  |  C2 |  D2 |  E2 | G2 | H2 |
A3 | B3  |  C3 |  D3 |  E3 | G3 | H3 |
A4 | B4  |  C4 |  D4 |  E4 | G4 | H4 |
```

The Column F has the parameter value to be include with merge(), as result I want the df Result

I'm using the code:

```
df Result = pd.merge(df Result, df Conditions[[A,B,C,D,E,F]], on = [A,B,C,D,E], how = 'left')
```

Currently, the result is getting only the F column that has the most number of conditions, but doesn't evaluate every condition.

```
A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  | G  | H  | F |
A1 | B1  |  C1 |  D1 |  E1 | G1 | H1 |   |
A2 | B2  |  C2 |  D2 |  E2 | G2 | H2 |   |
A3 | B3  |  C3 |  D3 |  E3 | G3 | H3 |   |
A4 | B4  |  C4 |  D4 |  E4 | G4 | H4 | F4|
```

How can I do this?

Comment: do you want to merge columns F to df_result ?

Comment: Yes, Initially I don´t have the column F in df_result but I have the F column attached to df Conditions.

I think that is like a Vlookup in excel but with more conditions that not necesarily will appear at the same time

Comment: df_Conditions = pd.merge(df_Result,df_Conditions, on ='A',allow_exact_matches = True )

Comment: Is there any other solution, The real df_Result has more columns and I can´t merge all the df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think of a way make use of multiple [`df.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with merge. Basic idea is to create multiple `wildcards` dataframe to the `None` values on different columns

```py
df_Conditions = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
                             data=[['A1', 'B1', None, None, None, 'F1'],
                                   ['A2', 'B2', None, None, None, 'F2'],
                                   ['A3', 'B3', None, 'D3', None, 'F3'],
                                   ['A4', 'B4', None, 'D4', 'E4', 'F4'],
                                   ])

df_Result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H'],
                         data=[['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'G1', 'H1'],
                               ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2', 'E2', 'G2', 'H2'],
                               ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3', 'E3', 'G3', 'H3'],
                               ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4', 'E4', 'G4', 'H4'],
                               ])
```

First merge as what you did, it should gives you an extra empty `column F`

```
res = pd.merge(df_Result, df_Conditions, on=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], how='left')
res
Out[8]: 
    A   B   C   D   E   G   H    F
0  A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  G1  H1  NaN
1  A2  B2  C2  D2  E2  G2  H2  NaN
2  A3  B3  C3  D3  E3  G3  H3  NaN
3  A4  B4  C4  D4  E4  G4  H4  NaN
```

Create a wildcard dataframe as a sub-dataframe of `df_Conditions`

```py
wildcards_C = df_Conditions[df_Conditions['C'].isnull()].dropna(axis=1, how='all')
wildcards_C
Out[10]: 
    A   B     D     E   F
0  A1  B1  None  None  F1
1  A2  B2  None  None  F2
2  A3  B3    D3  None  F3
3  A4  B4    D4    E4  F4
```

Merge it with `df_Result` and update the values on res

```py
res.update(df_Result.merge(wildcards_C, how='left'), overwrite=False)
res
Out[12]: 
    A   B   C   D   E   G   H    F
0  A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  G1  H1  NaN
1  A2  B2  C2  D2  E2  G2  H2  NaN
2  A3  B3  C3  D3  E3  G3  H3  NaN
3  A4  B4  C4  D4  E4  G4  H4   F4
```

It would update the columns F on `res` dataframe when values on columns A, B, D, E are matched. Repeat the same with conditions column E

```py
wildcards_E = df_Conditions[df_Conditions['E'].isnull()].dropna(axis=1, how='all')
res.update(df_Result.merge(wildcards_E, how='left'), overwrite=False)
res
Out[6]: 
    A   B   C   D   E   G   H    F
0  A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  G1  H1  NaN
1  A2  B2  C2  D2  E2  G2  H2  NaN
2  A3  B3  C3  D3  E3  G3  H3   F3
3  A4  B4  C4  D4  E4  G4  H4   F4
```

Finally repeat the same with conditions column D

```py
wildcards_D = df_Conditions[df_Conditions['D'].isnull()].dropna(axis=1, how='all')
res.update(df_Result.merge(wildcards_D, how='left'), overwrite=False)
res
Out[6]: 
    A   B   C   D   E   G   H   F
0  A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  G1  H1  F1
1  A2  B2  C2  D2  E2  G2  H2  F2
2  A3  B3  C3  D3  E3  G3  H3  F3
3  A4  B4  C4  D4  E4  G4  H4  F4
```

For demonstration purpose, I did not group the repetitions in a loop.

One drawback here is you have to analyze the order of "wildcard" yourself, current tactics: keep the column with least wildcards (i.e. column D) as long as possible.

Comment: Sorry, I checked my question and I notice that I wrote wrong the df that I want as result modifying as:

df Result = pd.merge(df Result, df Conditions[[A,B,C,D,E,F]], on = [A,B,C,D,E], how = 'left') I tried with your code but is not working. merge() just dont find all the conditions and NaN in the df Result (Column F) after running it. If you can help me I really appreciate that.

Comment: modified my answer, pls see if it looks better

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I tried with this code, but:

When I do:

df_Result = pd.merge(df_Result, df_Conditions['A','B','C','D','E','F'], on=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], how='left'). The Column F already has "F4", and applying the next steps nothing changes. Don't Know why its happenning. The wildcards has been created well.

Comment: I also tryed with: df_Result['F'] = df_Result['F'].replace(np.nan,'',regex=True) but is still only show 'F4'

Comment: Very likely you are not running the same piece of code as mine. It increases the complexity when we are not in sync. For example, i don't see the difference between `df_Conditions` and `df_Conditions[['A','B','C','D','E','F']]` when `df_Conditions` contains only columns `['A','B','C','D','E','F']`. Also, I am using another dataframe `res` to store the merge result instead of overriding `df_Result`. My suggestion of first step investigation is you try to copy what i have above (including the dataframes creation part), execute the code and see if we have same result.